# Django is not finding images linked via CSS file when in production

Tags: css, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles, django-settings

I have deployed a Django 2.2 project via Digital Ocean and it can be found at www.fancyfetish.co.uk

If you visit the site it looks awful, with a lot of images and styling missing. This is not the case when in development. When I use chrome dev tools to inspect the console there are 404 errors when retrieving images that have been called from the CSS file, along with a lot of CSS styling.

Find here a code snippet from my CSS file that is not being rendered at all:

```
.showcase {
  min-height: 40rem;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 15rem;
  padding-bottom: 10rem;
  background-image: url("/static/baseapp/img/fancy_fetish_showcase.png/");
  background-position: center 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; 
 }

  .showcase h3 {
    font-family: 'Cinzel', serif; 
  }

  .showcase h1 {
    font-family: 'Cinzel', serif; 
  }

  .showcase a {
    font-family: 'Peddana', serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem; 
  }
```

As shown in this section I clearly link the background-image back to the images folder. The particular images folder I am specifying is the one where all my static files go to when I use collectstatic.

The 404 error says:

> http://fancyfetish.co.uk/static/baseapp/css/fancy_fetish_showcase.png

So it is trying to find the CSS image within the css file, however it is located in the img folder within static.

Here is the link in my django template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'baseapp/css/style.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'baseapp/css/bootstrap.css' %}">
```

Here is the directory:

[image]

Within apps is a cart application, a user application, a products application and a baseapp where I keep all static folders, and link back to all of them from the other apps, so I don't have static files in every single app.

My settings files look like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    'apps/baseapp/static'
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

The main static directory in the directory image above is where collectstatic moves everything to, it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The media file found within the main directory is where images uploaded via the database go, as shown here in one of my models:

```
class ToyProduct(models.Model):

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    stock_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.CharField(choices=TOY_CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2, default='FW')
    brand = models.CharField(choices=TOY_BRAND_CHOICES, max_length=2, default='NB')
    on_sale = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I write my css in an SCSS file and Koala dev tool compiles to css which is then collected to the static folder.

I am pretty sure this is something very obvious and I am looking too far into it, or I have my static files in my settings wrong. Is anyone able to assist at all?

Most grateful regards!

Carlie

Comment: Which web server did you choose and have you configured it to serve static files? Django doesn’t just serve the files in production the same way it does in development.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu through digital ocean, with nginx, and I assumed there was an issue with CSS only as other static files and my bootstrap.css files seem to have loaded fine

Comment: If I look at the 'style.css' files, the url is not as you show here. It's `background-image: url("fancy_fetish_showcase.png");`. urls in css files are always **relative to the location of the css file itself**. Change it to `url("../img/fancy_fetish_showcase.jpg")`.

Comment: Note that if `baseapp` is one of your Django apps, Django already looks for files inside the `baseapp/static/` directory so you don't need to add it to `STATICFILES_DIRS`, as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files)

Comment: Also note that media files are uploaded to `MEDIA_ROOT` (in your settings), so if `MEDIA_ROOT` is a folder called "media" somewhere, you shouldn't `upload_to='media'` since that would upload your files in __path/to/media/media__, ie. two times "media".

Comment: Finally, I would advise you to put "media" and "static" folders (`MEDIA_ROOT` and `STATIC_ROOT`) **outside of your project folder**, so one level higher up. That way, when you deploy your source code, you don't run the risk of overwriting media and static. Especially since both need to be accessible by nginx, whereas your source folder doesn't need to be accessible by nginx (only by django process) so you can tighten security.

Comment: I am really unsure why my CSS file on the server has the URL as url("fancy_fetish_showcase.png") as this is not what it written in the CSS file that I am uploading to the server. There may be an error in my SCSS rendering, thank you for pointing this out to me. I will also take a look at my file structures for security. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url()` in css files always uses a path **relative to the location of the css file itself**.

Your **style.css** file contains `background-image: url("fancy_fetish_showcase.png");` so your browser is going to look for this file in the same folder as the css file (`/static/baseapp/css`).

You should replace this with `url("../img/fancy_fetish_showcase.jpg")` for it to look in `/static/baseapp/img`.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue, the server was accessing an old version of my css file through GIT. I recloned to repo and it updated to my latest working version of CSS and now all is working